# SSIS Business Intelligence LookUp task Visual studio Get Data

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence

please  i need your help, i have  stagging table on-`Air(*BTS*,Ville,region,zone)`
and table `dim_BTS(*BTS*,BSC,statut,date_BTS,classe,idVille) dimAxeGeographi(idVille,ville,zmr,region)`

and i need yor help how to get idVille from `dimAxeGeographi` and put it on `dim_BTS` by using attribute `BTS`  from stagging table  on SSIS on Business Intelligence  but i don't know how to get `Id-ville`.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: in table dimAxeGeographi, ville and region together make the record unique.

Try this:

```
Merge dim_BTS AS Target using
(
    SELECT A.BTS, D.idVille
    FROM Air A
    INNER JOIN dimAxeGeographi D 
        ON A.Ville = D.Ville AND A.Region = D. Region
) AS Source ON Source.BTS = Target.BTS

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET Target.idVille = Source.idVille
;
```

NOTE: It would be helpful if you can post sample data and expected result.

Comment: Thank you very much Anoop  to reply . i asked  where i will put this code on SSIS ?

Comment: Inside an Execute SQL Task on the control flow surface. You will have to decide the exact location within the flow. But before you do that test and tweak the code in SSMS.

Comment: In SSMS show me this error "The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.
"   can u please help me what can i do

Comment: Note the assumption at the beginning of my answer. you would need to resolve the duplicate issue before Merge can work. That's why I requested for sample data. Also, on a separate note, you do not need to open a new ticket for the same issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720727/merge-statement-ssis).

Comment: Or you can write a sp and execute it in `OLE DB Command` object