# Merge Statement SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, business-intelligence

I tested this code on SSMS

```
Merge dim_BTS AS Target using  
(
    SELECT  A.BTS, D.idVille  
    FROM onAir A  
    INNER JOIN dbo.DIM_AXE_GEO D   
        ON A.Ville = D.Villle   

) AS Source ON Source.BTS = Target.BTS  


WHEN MATCHED THEN  
UPDATE  
SET Target.idVille = Source.idVille;
```

show me this error

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source
>   row. A MERGE   statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the
>   target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target
>   row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to
>   group the source rows.

Can you please help me what can I do ?

Comment: Doesn't the syntax require to specify `AS Source(which columns)` ?

Comment: I specified  BTS  column from the source Table just for  to know the IDvILLE BY USING bts

Comment: you do not need to open a new ticket for the same issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710051/ssis-business-intelligence-lookup-task-visual-studio-get-data). –

Answer (score 1):

Your Source sub-query is returning duplicate rows with same `BTS` (column You use to join on target) which is not allowed for `MERGE` statement.

You can refine your query to filter only the latest row for each `BTS` using `ROW_NUMBER()` function in CTE

```
WITH CTE_Source AS 
(
    SELECT  A.BTS, D.idVille, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.BTS ORDER BY d.idVille DESC)  RN -- choose order of your preference
    FROM onAir A  
    INNER JOIN dbo.DIM_AXE_GEO D   
        ON A.Ville = D.Villle   
)
Merge dim_BTS AS Target using  
(
    SELECT  * FROM CTE_Source WHERE RN=1
) AS Source ON Source.BTS = Target.BTS  
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
UPDATE  
SET Target.idVille = Source.idVille;
```

Or if multiple row BTS needs to be inserted, you need to add more columns on ON clause when joining on target.

Comment: Thank you very much it's work now but can you help me how can i ad this code on SSIS please i need your help, i have stagging table on-Air(*BTS*,Ville,region,zone) and table dim_BTS(*BTS*,BSC,statut,date_BTS,classe,idVille) dimAxeGeographi(idVille,ville,zmr,region)
 
and dim_BTS it's empty best regards

Comment: @user2586714 Nothing different than how you usually add code to SSIS - using `ExecuteSQL` task.

Comment: yes i did inside an Execute SQL Task on the control flow surface.but dim_BTS is empty and what can i add on Data flow

Comment: http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2007/07/05/sql-server-2008-using-merge-from-ssis/ - You can use dataflow to prepare data (CTE + SELECT WHERE RN=1)  in temp table and then just have MERGE using temp table in executesql task

Comment: or you can put your whole MERGE inside stored procedure and just exec it from ssis

Comment: Thak you very much i'am new on SSIS i wantto ask you to create dimension table or fact tables i have to create for each table a package ?

Comment: You don't need new package for each table, just separate tasks in control flow.

Comment: Thank you Nenad Zivkovic and thank you very much to everybody for help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `SELECT` statement. You may have to add `DISTINCT`, or another `JOIN` condition, or a `WHERE` clause to make sure rows are not duplicated.

Comment: when i add top 1 idVille added on Dim_BTS but just one row changed and when i do top 10 doesn't work. iwant update alll idville on target Table  please help me :(

Comment: i tried this code but O rows affected what is the problem ?
Merge fact_table as target using( select top 1 idDatefin,PK_Date_fin,
Week_Of_Year
from dbo.dim_date_fin)as source 
on cast(source.PK_Date_fin as date)=cast(target.DATE_fin_ALaRM as date)
when matched then
update set target.ID_TEMP_DEB=source.idDatefin,
 target.NUMEROSEMAINE=source.Week_Of_Year;
heeeeelp please ;(